# Implicit Scheme: error type : ValueError : x and y must have same first dimension

Tags: python, matplotlib, valueerror

I am trying to implement a heat equation solver using the Euler scheme for time integration, here is the particular equation implemented :

[image]
And here is my code :

```
Nt = 20
Nx = 100
x = np.linspace(0,1,Nx+1)
t = np.linspace(0,1,Nt+1)

dx = 1/Nx
dt = 1/Nt
F = dt/(dx**2)



T_temps = np.zeros(Nx+1)
T = np.zeros(Nx+1)

for i in range(Nx+1):
    T_temps[i] = np.sin(x[i])

for n in range(0,Nt):
    for i in range(1,Nx):
        T[i] = T_temps[i] + F*(T_temps[i-1]-2*T_temps[i]+T_temps[i+1]) + ((np.pi**2)-1)*np.exp(-t[i])*np.sin(x[i])
    T[0] = 0.
    T[Nx] = 0.

    T_temps[:] = T
    
plt.plot(t,T)
plt.show()
```

It works when the two values of Nt and Nx are the same but when I have to modify the value of Nt for the exercise that've to do it générâtes this error :

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (101,) and (21,)
```

I Don't know how to deal with it : I understand the meaning but I Don't know how to avoid it ?

Thaks a lot for your help,

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I wanted to reproduce I hit index error. In `np.exp(-t[i])` should be `np.exp(-t[n])`. Then the whole line will be:

```
T[i] = T_temps[i] + F * (T_temps[i - 1] - 2 * T_temps[i] + T_temps[i + 1]) + ((np.pi ** 2) - 1) * np.exp(-t[n]) * np.sin(x[i])
```

You are trying to plot, 21 number (shape of `t`) in relation to 101 numbers (shape of `T`). To solve, change to `plt.plot(x, T)` as `x` and `T` has the same shape.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have corrected the line where you have found the error but for your final advice, I am not sure that is what I am asked for since the objective is to plot the temperature's evolution "T" as a function of time "t" first not "x" which is a spatial parameter… I Don't know if my point is correct here ? Thanks again for your help